# Timer function adding an extra Timer on each call

Tags: java, android, timer, intervals

Can anyone help me with my two Timer Functions:

The first one just makes the timer while canceling any previous one out first,
The second one just handles Cancelling the Timer

```
public void startInterval(int delay, int time, final String eventName){
    cancelInterval();
    mInterval = new Timer();
    mInterval.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Log.i("timer", "Interval");
        sendEvent(eventName, Arguments.createMap());
      }
    }, delay, time);
  }

public void cancelInterval() {
    if (mInterval != null){
      mInterval.cancel();
      mInterval.purge();
    }

    mInterval = null;
}
```

The problem is that the timer is multiplying every time I call it.

The first time I call, it works as intended, but after a few calls it ends up adding an extra timer per call

Comment: Note that when you cancel a timer, if the task was running at the time of cancel it will continue running to completion.  This may give the appearance of multiple timers running (particularly if 'sendEvent' is blocking or time consuming).

Comment: So I have it logging out in the SendEvent, every time I run the function it adds an extra timer though.